# Dynamic form with indeterminite number of items

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a class:

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view where I want objects for the class above created using inputs (so I have a textbox for Name and a date select type thing for Date). However, I want thev user to be able to click a link and through jquery/javascript another textbox and date select will be added to the form, and this can happen unlimited times.

How can I bind this to a model so that I can return it to my action method? Ideally the model would be something like:

```
class MyModel
{
    public string AProperty { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Apologies for the poor wording, struggling to describe what I want but I think this should get the point across.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a client-side template and then return JSON to your controller. If you are using MVC 3, JSON model binding is built-in, but in MVC 2 you need to set up your own binder. There is an example [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/).

I recommend using KnockoutJS for your client side. It's very simple for working with dynamic collections and very well documented. You can see an example similar to what you're trying to do [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html) as well as in the previous link.